# Possible to send one payment to multiple Paypal accounts?

Tags: paypal

I have a client who wants to setup a Paypal Buy it Now button on his small e-commerce store. The customer is able to say: "I want to make a payment of $20 and I want this percentage to go toward this purpose, and this percentage to go toward this other purpose." Is it possible to have one payment split up and go into two separate Paypal accounts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Paypal adaptive payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_APIntro) allows this

Answer (score 0):

Paypal has a 'Chained Payments' feature under its [Adaptive Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) that does exactly that